# Can I wrap NSLog in a block that takes a variable number of arguments?

Tags: objective-c, logging, objective-c-blocks

I’m writing an Objective-C library and I’d like it to offer a simple pluggable logging mechanism, so that the library user can turn the logging on and off. I thought an interesting way to do this would be a block property on the library classes:

```
typedef void (^Logger)(NSString *fmt, ...);
@property(copy) Logger logger;
logger(@"Foo, %@.", self);
```

But I don’t know how to pass the variable argument list to `NSLog`:

```
const Logger SimpleLogger = ^(NSString *fmt, ...) {
    // what goes in here?
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, I completely missed `NSLogv`:

```
const Logger SimpleLogger = ^(NSString *fmt, ...) {
    va_list arglist;
    va_start(arglist, fmt);
    NSLogv(fmt, arglist);
    va_end(arglist);
};
```